# CommandInvokationFailure: Unable to convert classes into dex format.Error:Invalid command dx

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

When I tried to package Android APK through unity, the following error occurred, and I couldn't find the reason for a long time，who can help me?

following error:

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Unable to convert classes into dex format.
/Users/mbj0578/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_231.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Xmx2048M -Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir="/Users/mbj0578/Library/Android/sdk/tools" -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -jar "/Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/2017.3.0f3/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/Tools/sdktools.jar" -

stderr[
Error:Invalid command dx
]
stdout[

]
exit code: 64
UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.RunCommandInternal (System.String javaExe, System.String sdkToolsDir, System.String[] sdkToolCommand, Int32 memoryMB, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.RunCommandSafe (System.String javaExe, System.String sdkToolsDir, System.String[] sdkToolCommand, Int32 memoryMB, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
```

this is my jdk version :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2FfPJ.png)

this is my AndroidManifet :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1DuZ.png)

who can help me ? thanks very much!

Comment: Upgrade unity or downgrade android sdk, dx was removed since API 31.

Comment: thank u very much, brother. your answer has helped me solve the problem that has troubled me for several days